# How to parse pusher.com's "serialized" json into qt5 QJsonDocument?

Tags: c++, json, websocket, qt5

I'm getting some json data from a pusher.com WebSocket in my qt5 app and I'm struggling to parse the "serialized" json they send. I finally identified the problem but I'm not sure how to solve it:

I made a small test program to demonstrate:

```
QString str1 = "{\"event\":\"message\",\"data\":\"{\\\"channel\\\":\\\"trade.3\\\",\\\"trade\\\":{\\\"tradeid\\\":\\\"86364698\\\",\\\"timestamp\\\":1425420405,\\\"datetime\\\":\\\"2015-03-03 17:06:45 EDT\\\",\\\"marketid\\\":\\\"3\\\",\\\"marketname\\\":\\\"LTC\\\\/BTC\\\",\\\"quantity\\\":\\\"0.24680554\\\",\\\"price\\\":\\\"0.00694988\\\",\\\"total\\\":\\\"0.00171527\\\",\\\"type\\\":\\\"Buy\\\"}}\",\"channel\":\"trade.3\"}";

QString str2="{\"event\":\"message\",\"data\": {\"channel\":\"trade.3\",\"trade\":{\"tradeid\":\"86364698\",\"timestamp\":1425420405,\"datetime\":\"2015-03-03 17:06:45 EDT\",\"marketid\":\"3\",\"marketname\":\"LTC\\/BTC\",\"quantity\":\"0.24680554\",\"price\":\"0.00694988\",\"total\":\"0.00171527\",\"type\":\"Buy\"}},\"channel\":\"trade.3\"}";

QJsonDocument doc1 = QJsonDocument::fromJson(str1.toUtf8());
QJsonDocument doc2 = QJsonDocument::fromJson(str2.toUtf8());

qDebug("%s", qPrintable(QString("Str1: \"%1\"").arg(str1)));
qDebug("%s", qPrintable(QString(doc1.toJson())));
qDebug() << "-----------------------------------------------------------";
qDebug("%s", qPrintable(QString("Str2: \"%1\"").arg(str2)));
qDebug("%s", qPrintable(QString(doc2.toJson())));
```

This outputs:

```
Str1: "{"event":"message","data":"{\"channel\":\"trade.3\",\"trade\":{\"tradeid\":\"86364698\",\"timestamp\":1425420405,\"datetime\":\"2015-03-03 17:06:45 EDT\",\"marketid\":\"3\",\"marketname\":\"LTC\\/BTC\",\"quantity\":\"0.24680554\",\"price\":\"0.00694988\",\"total\":\"0.00171527\",\"type\":\"Buy\"}}","channel":"trade.3"}"
{
    "channel": "trade.3",
    "data": "{\"channel\":\"trade.3\",\"trade\":{\"tradeid\":\"86364698\",\"timestamp\":1425420405,\"datetime\":\"2015-03-03 17:06:45 EDT\",\"marketid\":\"3\",\"marketname\":\"LTC\\/BTC\",\"quantity\":\"0.24680554\",\"price\":\"0.00694988\",\"total\":\"0.00171527\",\"type\":\"Buy\"}}",
    "event": "message"
}

-----------------------------------------------------------
Str2: "{"event":"message","data": {"channel":"trade.3","trade": {"tradeid":"86364698","timestamp":1425420405,"datetime":"2015-03-03 17:06:45 EDT","marketid":"3","marketname":"LTC\/BTC","quantity":"0.24680554","price":"0.00694988","total":"0.00171527","type":"Buy"}},"channel":"trade.3"}"
{
    "channel": "trade.3",
    "data": {
        "channel": "trade.3",
        "trade": {
            "datetime": "2015-03-03 17:06:45 EDT",
            "marketid": "3",
            "marketname": "LTC/BTC",
            "price": "0.00694988",
            "quantity": "0.24680554",
            "timestamp": 1425420405,
            "total": "0.00171527",
            "tradeid": "86364698",
            "type": "Buy"
        }
    },
    "event": "message"
}
```

Obviously the second version is my goal. Is there a way to easily convert the input data or am I going to have to try and roll my own converter function?

EDIT: The following does the trick on this particular data sample... but I'm still thinking there must be a more proper way to convert this sort of stuff...

```
str1.replace("\\\"", "\"");
str1.replace("\\\\", "\\");
str1.replace("\"{", "{");
str1.replace("}\"", "}");
```

Answer (score 0):

Your "data" is in fact another JSON document.

Just create another QJsonDocument from doc1.object()["data"].toString();

But it seams clear that "data" can have other things, it is a json doc in this example.

Good Luck!